# CountDownTimer in my class service stop when i destroy my class activity

Tags: java, android

i have countdowntimer in my service class and when i destroy my activity class then it stop my countdown timer in my service class but it didnt destroy my service class.
Can someone help me why my countdown timer stop? 
I need call another activity when my countdown is finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.google.co.id/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20make%20service%20keep%20alive%20when%20activity%20destroyed

after i searched from stackoverflow i got my answer here is it